# Creating a new column based on matches across other columns but ignoring the NAs when they appear

Tags: r, match

I'm trying to create a new column based on if there is a direct character match across multiple columns of the same row. I then want to put a 1 in the new column if there is a complete match across these columns, or a 0 if there is at least 1 nonmatch across the columns. Here's an example of the data:

```
  ID    var1   var2  var3
1     1     abc    def   abc
2     2     def    xyz   jkl
3     3     ghi    abc   abc
4     4     jkl    jkl   jkl
5     5     jkl    jkl   NA
6     6     abc    NA    NA
...
```

The final data should look something like this

```
     ID      var1  var2 var3 var_match
1     1     abc    def   abc      0
2     2     def    xyz   jkl      0
3     3     ghi    abc   abc      0
4     4     jkl    jkl   jkl      1
5     5     jkl    jkl   NA       1
6     6     abc    NA    NA       NA
...
```

I have tried this code:

```
df$var_match <-0
df <- within(df, { var_match<- ifelse(var1 == var2 & var1== var3, 1, 0) })
```

But this doesn't work with the NA's (like seen in line 5)- it'll give me an NA as a result instead of the desired 1. Let me know if there's some way around this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be

```
i1 <- df$var1 == df[3:4]
df$var_match <- as.integer(!rowSums(!i1, na.rm = TRUE) * 
            NA^(rowSums(is.na(i1)) == 2))
df$var_match
#[1]  0  0  0  1  1 NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, var1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", 
"jkl", "abc"), var2 = c("def", "xyz", "abc", "jkl", "jkl", NA
), var3 = c("abc", "jkl", "abc", "jkl", NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: What about the last column? When there are only NAs in var2 and var 3, so I want to keep the NA since there's nothing to match on?

Comment: @KaylaFinch  sorry, i was busy.  Updated the post

Comment: no problem. For illustration purposes, I simplified my data frame to match 1 column across 2 other columns, but in reality, I need to see if this value is found across 6 columns. I tried your code but changed the NA^(rowSums(is.na(i1)) == 2)) value to 6, and I only got NAs in the final column. Any idea on what's happening?

Comment: @Kayla  That would only happen if all the 6 column rows are NA for that particular row.   Can you check the `i1`

Comment: Never mind, found the problem. Looks like the code worked, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to edit this code so I can get a count of how many matches rather than just a 1 or 0?

Comment: @Kayla  Sure you can just do `sum(df$var_match, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun- Sorry I meant for within each row. So for instance, ID4 would have a sum of 2 (2 total matches) while ID5 would have 1 (only 1 match not including the NA)

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do something like this...

```
df$var_match <- as.integer(                                #convert to 1/0 from TRUE/FALSE
      apply(df[, -1],                                      #run through df, excluding col 1
            1,                                             #by rows
            function(x) {length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1 #test for one distinct value
                         & sum(!is.na(x)) > 1}))           #but more than one non-NA
```